# R - String Comparison in a Dataframe Column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with the following column:

| Description |
| --- |
| Boeing LTD |
| Boeing Limited |
| Boeing |
| Airbus Ltd |
| Airbus |

I want to compare the column value with each other to create another column that has a standardized description like this:

| Description | New Description |
| --- | --- |
| Boeing LTD | Boeing |
| Boeing Limited | Boeing |
| Boeing | Boeing |
| Airbus Ltd | Airbus |
| Airbus | Airbus |

I want to know how to apply `RecordLinkage::levenshteinSim` function in a way that it compares each column value against other column values to find the similarity score and then use that similarity score to create a standardized description in a new column.

Kindly help me to implement this logic.

Comment: Are these really the _only_ values which you have?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, I have more values. Most of them are unique values but some are duplicates with similar patterns as shared in the example dataset. I want to standardize those duplicates.